# module not found: Can't resolve '../types/index'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have spent about an hour trying to figure out this error but haven't had any luck.

I have types `index.d.ts` in folder types. The content of the types looks like this

```js
    export interface tag {
      created_at: string
      id: number
      name: string
    }
    
    export interface task {
      created_at: string
      id: number
      title: string
      updated_at: string
      tags: tag[]
    }
    
    export interface allTaksAndTags {
      tags: tag[]
      tasks: task[]
    }
```

When I am trying to import them, I am getting following error

Failed to compile.

> ./src/components/task.tsx Module not found: Can't resolve
> '../types/index' in '/Users/h/Desktop/timetracking/src/components'

I have attached below the screenshot, Can someone help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong here?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Type definition files are not meant to be used like that.

Remove `d.ts` in your index file and change its name as `index.ts`

Type definition files are automatically generated when you build your typescript project.